# How to handle multiple non-null column values in case statement while performing calculation

Tags: sql, mysql

I've a table below like this:

```
id  lg0 lg7 lg30
1   0   1   0
1   1   0   1
2   0   1   0
2   1   0   1
```

what i want to achieve:

```
id  window  value (lg0,lg7,lg30 columns)
1   0   1
1   7   0
1   30  0
2   0   0
2   7   1
2   30  0
3   0   0
3   7   0
3   30  1
```

window column is basically derived based on the three columns lg0, lg7, lg30 : when lg0 is not null then window column value is 0, when lg7 is not null then value would be 7 and similarly for 30.

I've written the below query using case statement but it's only considering lg0 so far because of non-null values in all three columns and gives the precedence to lg0 every time. i want to avoid the union operation for optimization purpose.

```
select id,
,case 
    when lg0 IS NOT NULL
    then 0
    when lg7 IS NOT NULL
    then 7
    when lg30 IS NOT NULL
    then 30
end as window
,case 
    when lg0 IS NOT NULL
    then lg0
    when lg7 IS NOT NULL
    then lg7 
    when lg30 IS NOT NULL
    then lg30
end as value
from table
```

Comment: The sample data contains id 1 and 2 only, but the expected result also includes id = 3. As desired?

Comment: @jarlh that's just for illustration ID can have more values

Comment: A [mcve] is expected to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler stops checking conditions after the first successful condition in an SQL CASE statement, hence for each id, it will only satisfy the first NON NULL checking condition.
As a solution, I guess, we would need to add a condition where the values (lg0, lg7, lg30) are not null. As these are different columns in the given table, we can create a new table combining the values in one and then CROSS JOIN.
I suppose the following approach would work for the use case:

```
SELECT t.id,
       c.window,
       c.value
FROM your_table t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    VALUES
        (0, t.lg0),
        (7, t.lg7),
        (30, t.lg30)
) AS c(window, value)
WHERE c.value IS NOT NULL
```